Representing optional blocks in a block definition diagram SysML
I'm trying to create a block definition diagram in SysML that includes optional blocks and, conditioned by the presence of that optional block, to introduce new associated connections and modify existing ones. The introduction of each one of those optional blocks could be called a new configuration.
Currently I have been creating a new block definition diagram for each one of those configurations, but it takes away from the overview of the complete system architecture. I would like to know if there is a way to represent all of that information into one bdd, also including information which blocks can be present simultaneously, which are mutually exclusive, etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What blocks are or are not shown on a diagram bears no meaning for the model. So, you need to come up with a different way to model optionality. An example would help to discuss the possiblities.
